# how to disable onbeforeunload when a condition becomes true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Test page that User can answer it In a specified time.

For Time limitation, I used a javascript countdown timer . until time is not finished, user Must not be able to closing window.

For that I used `onbeforeunload` window event to prevent window closing like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
</script>
```

In the other hand, in countdown timer , I set a `timeUp` function that redirects user to result page after finishing time.

In this case, because firing above `onbeforeunload`, redirects fails and above message is shown to User.

Is there any way So that could disable `onbeforeunload` event when a condition becomes true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `onbeforeunload` function will not return anything - the browser will not display any message.

Since you said that you used a timer function to check if you should display the user the message or not.

```
var displayMessage = true;
setTimeout(function() {
    displayMessage = false;
}, 10000);

function confirmExit() {
    if (displayMessage) {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

In the above code - after 10 seconds the value of displayMessage will be false, and if the user will try to refresh/exit the page after 10 seconds the browser will not display the message.

Answer (score 2):

Call **unbind** using the beforeunload event handler:

```
 $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
```

or try try

```
 window.onbeforeunload = null;`
```